# Unrestricted web access option in iTunes Connect app submission process query

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am looking to submit an app for review by the Apple team - the app is geared towards schoolchildren upto the ages of 17 - when I attempt to submit I see an option called **Unrestricted Web Access** Yes or No.

If I select Yes it states my app age rating is 17+, if I select no this changes to 4+.

My app doesn't have any ability to load a browser within the app so I would presume I can simply set this to No?

I obviously don't want to get the app rejected especially as it seems to take Apple forever to review it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unrestricted Web Access** means user can browse any url like a web browser. If you are simply using a `UIWebView` to display your web contents loading through a url that will be called "Restricted Web Access" I think.

You can simply set "Unrestricted Web Access" to "No"

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an internal web browser or UIWebView which allows to the user access to any URL you have to select YES or your app will be Metadata Rejected.